# Filtering a Custom List by Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, page-layout

I am using O365 SharePoint. I want to create a custom list (hypothetically) about dogs with a column "Dog Name", "Dog Breed", "age", etc. For example, one of the rows includes a 2-year-old golden retriever named Max.

I want to have all dogs in this master list, regardless of breed, because one of its functions is to allow me to collectively search all dogs. For example, I may be interested in finding all dogs that are 2 years old, even German Shepherds.

Now I have a page called "Golden Retrievers". It has a bunch of general info about golden retrievers. Now I want to insert that custom list and display only (filter) golden retrievers, which should include Max (among others).

I recognize that one way to do this is to create a view for my custom list and define the view on my custom list app; however, this dog example is just hypothetical; in my real scenario, there could be more than 50 *dog breeds*, exceeding the 50 public view limit. Is there another more dynamic way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it was the classic SharePoint pages, I would use one of the search web parts Content Search Web Part preferably or Content query web part.